# Search short text against large list of search terms

Tags: search

I have a short piece of text (more specifically a Tweet, so maximum length of 140 characters) that I would like to perform a search against approximately 100,000 terms.

It is turning the classical search problem on its head (large document, small search term). The naive approach of iterating through each of the search times and attempting to map can not be the most efficient way of tackling this problem.

Does anyone any resources or insights on how to tackle this type of a search problem?

Comment: Would you be open to loading the tweet and terms into a database (e.g. MySQL or SQL Server or such) and doing full text indexing on them? Or using a tool such as Solr?

Comment: Wasn't planning on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon the Aho-Corasick algorithm which is working very well for this situation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Using a Javascript implementation I am able to get the following performance:

Words to match: Abridged English Dictionary (~250,000 words)

Sentences per second performance: ~80,000

Some extra filtering is necessary to check for word boundaries if that is important to your use. The algorithm spits out the match location in the text, so it is trivial to efficiently check for word boundaries.

Hope this helps someone searching for similar problem :)